# Enable / Disable Swipe on radlistview

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-telerik-ui, radlistview

I'm building an app using nativescript, javascript and telerik ui.
I need need to know how crate a function to enable / disable the swipaction on radlistview by code.
Best regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using the `swipeActions="true"` of RadListView from the nativescript-telerik-ui plugin in order to implement an enable/disable solution all that you need to do is:

- Attach an handle for the `itemSwiping` event as shown [here](https://github.com/telerik/nativescript-ui-samples-angular/blob/master/listview/app/examples/swipe-actions/listview-swipe-disable.component.html#L3)
- In the handler set the `returnValue` of the arguments to the desired boolean value, as shown [here](https://github.com/telerik/nativescript-ui-samples-angular/blob/master/listview/app/examples/swipe-actions/listview-swipe-disable.component.ts#L91)

The same example is available in the official nativescript-telerik-ui sdk repository for Angular [here](https://github.com/telerik/nativescript-ui-samples-angular/blob/master/listview/app/examples/swipe-actions) and for Vanila {N} [here](https://github.com/telerik/nativescript-ui-samples/blob/master/listview/app/examples/swipe-actions) (look for the files with *swipe-disable* in their name)

Comment: I'm trying to implements swipes using ListView (not Rad) and it doesn't work consistently - takes a few swipes before getting a single notification. Will this solution also work for built-in ListView.

Comment: No this solution is only for RadListView. As your original post did not mention that you are using a specific component I gave you the best solution possible with the current state of the ListView components in {N}

Comment: Thank you for noticing, I updated my response with the working links. This change was due to the NativeScript UI demo apps being split into their own demo app across all components